# Получение пути текущего проекта C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Как в консольном приложении на C++ получить путь к текущему проекту ? Можно ли как-то использовать для этого переменные IDE, такие как $(TargetDir), например ?

Comment: Именно путь к проекту, где лежат исходники?

Comment: Да, именно так )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Идём в настройки проекта. Далее:
*Configuration Properties->Debugging->Command Arguments*. Жмём *Edit...* в этом поле, после чего появляется диалог. Выбираем *Macros>>*, далее выбираем нужный нам макрос и нажимаем *Insert*. Вам нужен `$(ProjectDir)`.
После этого, в коде, получить нужный нам параметр очень просто:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    cout << argv[1] << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете написать внешний скрипт, к примеру на Python, который будет знать месте расположения вашего проекта. В процессе сборки проекта он пусть запускается первым и зная место расположения будет изменять *.cpp файл.

Answer (score 1):

Если сборка проекта осуществляется через CMake, то можно использовать переменную `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` (абсолютный путь до директории, где расположен текущий CMakeLists.txt), либо переменную `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` (абсолютный путь до директории, где расположен корневой CMakeLists.txt).

Если необходимо использовать значения этих переменных в исходном коде, то можно добавить следующую команду:

```
target_compile_definitions(${target} PRIVATE RESOURCES_DIR=\"${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/resources\")
```

Теперь можно использовать макрос `RESOURCES_DIR` в коде.

Comment: Спасибо, полезно )

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно чтобы путь был известен при работе из IDE, то, как верно было указано в ответе @ixSci, можно передавать `$(ProjectDir)`. Но как только приложение будет скомпилировано и перенесено на другой компьютер, работать это перестанет. Можно воспользоваться советом из ответа @sys_dev и написать внешний скрипт. А можно использовать стандартный макрос, который есть в любом уважающем себя компиляторе - `__FILE__`. Этот макрос после обработки препроцессором превращается в путь и имя текущего файла.

Следует иметь в виду, что в *GCC/MinGW* будет путь и имя, а в *MSVC++* - только имя. Чтобы *MSVC++* выдала ещё и путь, нужно добавить компилятору параметр `/FC` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx).

Comment: А какой смысл имеет путь к проекту на другом компьютере? Вообще, вне среды он смысл имеет нулевой.

Comment: @ixSci Ак то ж его знает? Всё может быть. ;-) Я использовал. Но, правда, не путь, а путь с именем файла. Записывал его в лог.

Comment: Ну путь к файлу в логе это стандартная практика, с обрезанием полного пути и оставлением относительного. Но файл проекта, его путь, это только для целей отладки. Ни о каком релизе тут речи быть не может